# Record data stream from curl to text file

Tags: curl

I'm trying to record some data that streams in from the command:

`curl https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/events?access_token=blahblahtoken`

That curl command will listen to particle's cloud and print out any messages I send or receive between my particle devices to the terminal. I want to save the output to a text file.

I've tried:

- curl url > output.txt
- curl url >> output.txt
- curl url -o output.txt

Nothing has worked, on a Mac, or in linux. The file gets created, (or truncated if applicable), but nothing ever gets written to the file, even when a duplicate terminal window is printing output from the curl command.

My only guess is that the curl command continues indefinitely until I ctrl+C out of it, and maybe quitting that way prevents output from being recorded to the file? How can I record output to a file as the data comes in?

Comment: I was going to recommend `telnet api.particle.io 80` and then

    GET /v1/devices/events?access_token=blahblahtoken
    Host: api.particle.io

But then I noticed it's https, so that is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working with cURL for about a decade, and I don't know any way to get it to stream data like that from the command line. There is a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION that you can use in the C API, but I doubt you want to be writing your own C modules. I scanned the man page and couldn't find any similar option available in the CLI. I don't think that cURL command line offers an option to do what you need. As you suspect, it waits until the entire page is received before output (which is often necessary with pages being compressed).

Comment: Curl is new to me, but I've used C enough to be comfortable with writing my own module if it gets the job done. I'll give it a go when I get home, are there any particular examples you'd recommend looking at to get familiar with the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION?

Answer (score 1):

From https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html ...

-N, --no-buffer

Disables the buffering of the output stream. In normal work situations, curl will use a standard buffered output stream that will have the effect that it will output the data in chunks, not necessarily exactly when the data arrives. Using this option will disable that buffering.

I use this option to process data while it arrives, so I don't have to wait until the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question also hoping to log a particle event stream from curl. Since curl can't do that, I wrote a quick node script that does what I needed. Putting it here in case it's helpful for anyone else. Note that the "EventListener" needs to match the event string that your particle is emitting (in this case 'currentTime'):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var EventSource = require('eventsource');
var fs = require('fs');

var URL = 'https://api.particle.io/v1/products/power-monitor-v001/events?access_token=XXXXXXXX';

var es = new EventSource(URL);
es.addEventListener('currentTime', function (e) {
  console.log(e.data)
  fs.appendFileSync('test.json', e.data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the streaming output to a jsonl file. Every chunk will be saved independently.

```
curl -X GET YOURURL -o somefile.jsonl
```

That worked for me at least.