# Saving curl streaming-API output to a file

Tags: curl, archive

I am trying to stream data from Mastodon with the streaming API and save it to some kind of file.
For that I am using curl as follows:

```
curl -X GET 'https://masto.don/api/v1/streaming/public' -H 'Authorization: Bearer MYSUPERSECRETTOKEN'
```

My problem is, writing this ongoing stream of data to a file does not work with regular operators in bash such as ">>". Are there only certain file types that are usable for this job because every txt file I tried to generate from the output was empty.

Comment: Until now I could only find bad news, such as these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512790/record-data-stream-from-curl-to-text-file. I am aware of this question, I just hope someone might know a way or an "easy" alternative.

Comment: Nevermind, it appears it all works fine if you do use it with output but you need to output it to a "jsonl" file. This did the job:  "curl  -X GET YOURURL -H Authorization: MYSUPERSECRETTOKEN -o somefile.json"